# JPA Many to Many

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

Here is how I create my database:

```
CREATE TABLE actor(id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE movie(id INT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(255), release_date VARCHAR(255), duration INT, type VARCHAR(255), director VARCHAR(255), category VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE movie_actor(movie_id INT NOT NULL, actor_id INT NOT NULL);
```

And here is my java code:

```
@Entity
public class Actor {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="actorList")
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
//getters and setters
}
```

And second class.

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String releaseDate;
    private int duration;
    private String type;
    private String director;   
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_actor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id"))
    private List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MovieCategory category;
//getters and setters
}
```

Repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Integer> {
}
@Repository
public interface ActorRepository extends JpaRepository<Actor, Integer> {
}
```

Somebody have maybe any idea what I am doing wrong here? Because it doesn't work. I can't get movies by using `.findAll()`.

@edit

Can I use only `OneToMany` in `Movies` and ignore any adnotations in `Actor`? Becuase in this way it works, but I have no idea if it is correct. I just want to display movies with actor list, I don't need it in other way. But in one movie can play a lot of actors, and each actor can play in a lot of movies so I thought it should be ManyToMany.

Comment: where is your debugging? like looking at the SQL invoked by the JPA provider, so you can see what is wrong with its queries, or schema mapping?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated after edit**

Ok, if you want to go only from one side, then that is a uni-directional collection mapping.

You can remove a mapping from Actor and Movie should be like this:

```
@OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_actor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id"))
    private List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<Actor>();
```

In this kind of set-up the @OneToMany should without the 'mappedBy' attribute.

Comment: It now display spam of first Movie from list when I want to display all movies :/

Comment: Show me your query

Comment: If you want to just use the .findAll() of the JpaRepository, then you might need to add @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) to your mapping

Comment: Ok after your update, yes that is an uni-directional collection mapping. See my updated psot